# How to save a header from an http response

Tags: scala, gatling

i'm trying to build a scenario where the user log in first, then do something before logging out.
The problem is that i want to save the header response from the log in request to use it in my next request.

When a user log in, he gets an header response containing the Authorization header, with the token.

Here is my code, but it's not working :

```
val LoggingTest = scenario("Basic Scenario")
      .exec(http("Logging")
      .post("/login")
      .body(
        StringBody("""{"name" : "test",
          "password" : "test"}""")
      )
      .check(header("Authorization").saveAs("token"),status.is(200))
    ).pause(15)

    .exec(http("check")
    .get("/sayhi")
    .header("Authorization",s"${token}")
    .check(status.is(200))
    ).pause(15)
```

How can i fix it please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```scala
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

val LoggingTest: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Basic Scenario")
  .exec(http("Logging")
     .post("/login")
     .body(
        StringBody("""{"name" : "test",
        "password" : "test"}""")
     )
     .check(header("Authorization").saveAs("token"),status.is(200))
   ).pause(15)
   .exec( 
     http("check")
       .get("/sayhi")
       .header("Authorization", session => session("token").validate[String])
       .check(status.is(200))
   ).pause(15)
```

Comment: Thanks, i just tried it and it's working. I found another way by using HeaderRegex, but i still prefer yours, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

It's not `s"${token}"` but `"${token}"` without the `s`.

Sadly, IntelliJ automatically adds this `s` because it thinks you want to use Scala's String interpolation while you want to use Gatling Expression Language.